# Suggestion for creating crossbrowser web site GUI with ruby on rails?

Tags: javascript, css

I am working on a web app with Ruby on Rails and sometimes I got some cross browser compatibility issues with css, javascript. Do you have any suggestions to minimize such problems in such a web design process? Do you suggest to use external JS and CSS librares?

Answer (score 2):

You can use jQuery to help you deal with the DOM , it is more difficult to deal with CSS differences , but a grid framework like 960 grids can help for the layout. Eventually you'll have to check yourself on different browsers wether your app works well or not.